# MapBox Map is not initialized when trying to get user location | Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mapbox

I am trying to get user location in android using MapBox. My map is in Fragment. This is how I am initializing it.

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?

): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false)
    mapView = root.findViewById(R.id.map_view)
    mapView?.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    mapView?.getMapAsync { mapboxMap ->

        mapboxMap.setStyle(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS) {
            enableLocationComponent(it)
        }
    }
    return root
}
```

The app is crashing when I am trying to call *enableLocationComponent(it)*. Normally when I am calling it from *onMapReady()* it is working properly. But this is a different case. I don't really know where to put the *enableLocationComponent(it)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found a solution.

I had to move the style set to *onMapReady* function from Fragment *onCreateView*. And than I can call *enableLocationComponent()*.

The final code looks like this:

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?

): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false)
    mapView = root.findViewById(R.id.map_view)
    mapView?.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    mapView?.getMapAsync(this)
    return root
}

override fun onMapReady(mapboxMap: MapboxMap) {
    this.mapboxMap = mapboxMap
    mapboxMap.setStyle(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS) {
        enableLocationComponent(it)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if `onMapReady()` called by set a boolean `true` then run `enableLocationComponent(it)` :))
or in `onMapReady()` call a `Handler` to run `enableLocationComponent(it)` where you want.

something like this:

```
var mapLoaded = false
override fun onMapReady(@NonNull mapboxMap:MapboxMap) {
        this.mapboxMap = mapboxMap
        mapboxMap.setStyle(Style.Builder().fromUri(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS)
            .withSource(GeoJsonSource(CIRCLE_GEOJSON_SOURCE_ID))
            .withSource(GeoJsonSource(LINE_GEOJSON_SOURCE_ID)), object:Style.OnStyleLoaded {
            override fun onStyleLoaded(@NonNull style1:Style) {
                mapLoaded = true //then chack this value if is ture call enableLocationComponent(it)
            }
        })
    }
```

or

```
        lateinit var mHandler : Handler
    
    // initialize this where you want call your function
        mHandler = object:Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
              override fun handleMessage(message:Message) {
                   enableLocationComponent(it)
              }
        }

//onMapReady bi like this
        override fun onMapReady(@NonNull mapboxMap:MapboxMap) {
             this.mapboxMap = mapboxMap
             mapboxMap.setStyle(Style.Builder().fromUri(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS)
                  .withSource(GeoJsonSource(CIRCLE_GEOJSON_SOURCE_ID))
                  .withSource(GeoJsonSource(LINE_GEOJSON_SOURCE_ID)), object:Style.OnStyleLoaded {
                   override fun onStyleLoaded(@NonNull style1:Style) {
                          mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0)
                     }
                })
           }
```

Comment: The problem is, that my solution does not use onMapReady(). And if I try to use it, nothing happens. The style is set in this fragment builder onCreateView() or I don't know what is it. It is set using this: 

mapView?.getMapAsync { mapboxMap ->

            mapboxMap.setStyle(Style.MAPBOX_STREETS) {
                //enableLocationComponent(it)
            }
        }